# Unsupported Feature Error Ref Cursor for SqlInOutParameter in a Spring

Tags: java, spring-boot, oracle11g

I have to execute a stored procedure with has 13 parameters.  There are input, output and input/input parameters. I am calling the stored procedure from a Spring Boot Java web service.
The stored procedure throws an exception of:

> SQL state [99999]; error code [17023]; Unsupported feature:
>   sqlType=-10;

when I use an input/output parameter that is a reference cursor.
(I created a store procedure for input, output, or in/out parameters that are of type string or integer and it works fine.  But it is the cursor that is the problem.

This is the code that calls the stored procedure:

```
MapSqlParameterSource parameterSource = new MapSqlParameterSource();
parameterSource.addValue("p_input_stream", input);
parameterSource.addValue("p_cur", null);

simpleJdbcCall.withCatalogName(PACKAGE).withProcedureName(PROCEDURE_TEST);
simpleJdbcCall.declareParameters(
    new SqlParameter("p_input_stream", OracleTypes.VARCHAR), 
    new SqlInOutParameter("p_cur", OracleTypes.CURSOR, new LoadCursorMapper()));
result = simpleJdbcCall.execute(parameterSource);
```

I am using the ResultSetExtractor interface to map the result set for the cursor.
This is the class:

```
public class LoadCursorMapper implements ResultSetExtractor<LoadCursor> {

    public LoadCursor extractData(ResultSet resultSet) throws SQLException, DataAccessException {

         LoadCursor trailer = new LoadCursor();
         trailer.setTrlrNbr(resultSet.getBigDecimal("trlr_nbr"));
         trailer.setTrlrPrefix(resultSet.getString("trlr_prefix"));           
         trailer.setCatgoryCodeLoadCondStat(resultSet.getString("catg_code_load_cond_stat"));
         trailer.setDetailCodeLoadCondStat(resultSet.getString("detl_code_load_cond_stat"));

        return trailer;
    }
}
```

I am not sure if the way I am declaring the cursor parameter is correct.
This code particularly:

```
new SqlInOutParameter("p_cur", OracleTypes.CURSOR, new LoadCloseSummaryTrailerCursorMapper()));
```

When running the service, I get the error:

> SQL state [99999]; error code [17023]; Unsupported feature:
>   sqlType=-10;

Any suggestions would be appreciated.

**UPDATE**
I have also tried the RowMapper interface and get the same error.

How can I use an Oracle Cursor as an input parameter in Java?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This how I solved the problem...
First, I did not add the in/out parameter as an input parameter in the MapSqlParameterSource.  These values in my instance are always null.
So my MapSqlParameterSource looks like this:

```
MapSqlParameterSource parameterSource = new MapSqlParameterSource();
parameterSource.addValue("p_input_stream", input);
```

Then I declared the parameter as only an output parameter in JdbcSimpleCall like this:

```
simpleJdbcCall.declareParameters(
    new SqlParameter("p_input_stream", OracleTypes.VARCHAR), 
    new SqlOutParameter("p_cur", OracleTypes.CURSOR, new LoadCursorMapper()));
```

This worked for me...

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if it helps a lot, but I did a quick search on this error:

> SQL state [99999]; error code [17023]; Unsupported feature: sqlType=-10;

It seems that you might have a problem with your Oracle driver. It may not support Cursors.
It's kind of a long shot, but give it a try.

Comment: The web service uses an oracle 12 driver and the database uses oracle 11 driver